# XML Python Choosing one of numerous attributes using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

As far as I know this question is not a repeat, as I have been searching for a solution for days now and simply cannot pin the problem down. I am attempting to print a nested attribute from an XML document tag using Python. I believe the error I am running into has to do with the fact that the tag I from which I'm trying to get information has more than one attribute. Is there some way I can specify that I want the "status" value from the "second-tag" tag?? Thank you so much for any help.

My XML document 'test.xml':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<first-tag xmlns="http://somewebsite.com/" date-produced="20130703" lang="en" produced-   by="steve" status="OFFLINE">
    <second-tag country="US" id="3651653" lang="en" status="ONLINE">
    </second-tag>
</first-tag>
```

My Python File:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
whatiwant = root.find('second-tag').get('status')
print whatiwant
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: I've narrowed it down. If I make the "xmlns" attribute ANYTHING other than what it is, it works fine. But, I cannot modify these XML's as I am pulling them from a large database... how do I simply get my python file to ignore this attribute?

Comment: Whenever you're spending days searching for a solution with a complex expression, you'll almost always benefit from breaking it down into separate simple expressions. In other words, change `whatiwant = root.find('second-tag').get('status')` to `second = root.find('second-tag')`, followed by `whatiwant = second.get('status')`. If you did that, you'd immediately see that the attribute is irrelevant here, because you never even get to that part of the code. (Someone sufficiently experienced can already tell that given the text of the exception—but if you can't, make your life easier.)

Comment: @abarnert, applied your changes and am unfortunately getting the same error.

Comment: Of course you get the same error. The point is that you can tell which of the two lines the error is on, which would tell you that the problem has nothing to do get `get(attribute)`, and everything to do with `find(element)`, which means you can ask a better question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fail at .find('second-tag'), not on the .get.

For what you want, and your idiom, BeautifulSoup shines.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml_string)
whatyouwant = soup.find('second-tag')['status']
```

Comment: Note that `BeautifulStoneSoup` is deprecated; with the last 3.x version, or any 4.x version, you will get a warning for using it. Just use `BeautifulSoup(xml_string, 'xml')`—or, if you're using 4.x, it will figure out automatically that you're dealing with XML as long as there's a proper header, so you don't even need that.

Comment: @EzraNugroho I installed beautifulsoup, and restarted my command prompt (bash) and am getting the error "ImportError: No module named BeautifuSoup". I added your imports to the top, and the touched up my whatiwant line. Any ideas?

Comment: @stmyd, did you install BeautifulSoup 3 or 4? if you downloaded the source, chances are it's 4. The import line is now: From bs4 import BeautifulSoup, and just as abamert says, you instantiate it with BeautifulSoup(xml_string, 'xml')

I find bs4 to be still a bit buggy. But for this small sample, it will be just fine

Comment: I installed 4. Now when I add this, how do I reference my XML file, as I did before with `tree = ET.parse('test.xml')`

Comment: Pardon my question I misunderstood you, I realize i have to substitute `xml_string` for `test.xml`, correct?

Comment: @EzraNugroho any reason why I am still getting the `no module named beautifulsoup`? my code appears as such now after i installed 4.4.2 `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
xml_string = open('EP98905126.xml').read()
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml_string, 'xml')
whatiwant = soup.find('bibliographic-data')['status']
print whatiwant`

Comment: It worked! I was being dumb and didn't specify my file. Thank you @abarnert and @EzraNugroho!!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know with elementtree but i would do so with ehp or easyhtmlparser
here is the link.
http://easyhtmlparser.sourceforge.net/
a friend told me about this tool im still learning thats pretty good and simple.

```
from ehp import *

data = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<first-tag xmlns="http://somewebsite.com/" date-produced="20130703" lang="en" produced-   by="steve" status="OFFLINE">
    <second-tag country="US" id="3651653" lang="en" status="ONLINE">
    </second-tag>
</first-tag>'''

html  = Html()
dom   = html.feed(data)
item = dom.fst('second-tag')
value = item.attr['status']
print value
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that there is no tag named `second-tag` here. There's a tag named `{http://somewebsite.com/}second-tag`.

You can see this pretty easily:

```
>>> print(root.getchildren())
[<Element '{http://somewebsite.com/}second-tag' at 0x105b24190>]
```

A non-namespace-compliant XML parser might do the wrong thing and ignore that, making your code work. A parser that bends over backward to be friendly (like `BeautifulSoup`) will, in effect, automatically try `{http://somewebsite.com/}second-tag` when you ask for `second-tag`. But `ElementTree` is neither.

If that isn't all you need to know, you first need to read a tutorial on namespaces (maybe [this one](http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm)).